# How to have a full width gradient background on a child that is inside a centered relative parent

Tags: html, css, width, gradient

[image: Full width gradient background sample]
To get design B, we can easily set the parent container to be 100vw width, flex display and justify-content center.

However, in my use case, I would need to give the parent a max-width for some reason as in A. The parent container in A is given a light blue color for better illustration (it is originally transparent). Now I have difficulty to achieve the same design of full width gradient B in A's first two sentences.

I came up with two incomplete solutions but they did not solve my problems. I do not know how to let the children to have full width background gradient while staying in centered relative parent.

For solution 2, I do not know how to set a negative margin-left to the `::before` pseudoelement while retaining responsiveness at the same time.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/leeyh/pen/vYrPNNV

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: #33A2FF33;
}

.solution1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}

.solution2 {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.solution2::before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}

.sample {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Some super loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong
    loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooong text
  </p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="solution1">Title</h1>
    <h2 class="solution2">
      another lengthy textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textssssssssssstexts
    </h2>
    <p>content without gradient</p>
    <p>content without gradient</p>
  </div>
  <p>------</p>
  <p>------</p>
  <p>------</p>
  <p>------</p>
  <p>------</p>
  <div class="sample">
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>
        another lengthy textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textsssssssssss textssssssssssstexts
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following code based on this [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-when-use-css-calc-tutorial-examples/?fbclid=IwAR3skvt_twEPv4qhbmSJVv9yZw8XOUCzuYZqt4maOjKy40FLig8yVSQo0Gk)

```
.solution2::before{
  content:'';
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
  margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);  //<---- solution
}
```

Comment: An explanation to the code is always great as it makes the code clear to everyone